# .htaccess for friendly URL with multiple variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am working on making my site more SEO friendly I am currently using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)$ index.php?page=$1
```

To turn `site.co.uk/index.php?page=page_name` into `site.co.uk/page_name`

I want to also use this for sub pages too.
I have tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2
```

but its not working, it runs `site.co.uk/page_name/sub_page` but when you go to `site.co.uk/page_name` it returns the 404 not found.

I want it to run `site.co.uk/page_name` and it return `page_name`

or

`site.co.uk/page_name/sub_page` and return `sub_page`

and so on

`site.co.uk/page_name/sub_page/sub_page2/...`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using just:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

is fine then you can route the request within your script.

You split the page variable with explode() delimiter / and then set the variables.

```
$route = explode('/',$_GET['page']);

$page    = isset($route[0]) ? $route[0] : null;
$subpage = isset($route[1]) ? $route[1] : null;
$yada    = isset($route[2]) ? $route[2] : null;
```

Many MVC frameworks use this method. Its called routing.

Comment: +1 as it's the simplest and most flexible. You can even do it without passing "page" just by parsing the REQUEST_URI. Also add "RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d" if you have browsable directories.

Comment: Thank you so much i been picking my head for ages over this .htaccess is the only thing im unsure about. thank you @Lawrence Cherone

Comment: im using `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php` to hide the exstention how do i use `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]` on a page called `portal.php` (`portal` with the rewrite rule) to do the same but with it like (`portal/` to be the page) and `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]` like ¬RewriteRule ^(.*)$ portal/?page=$1 [L,QSA]` or something like that.

Comment: this solution is so perfect, thank you so much. Worked perfectly