# Cleaning a url with multiple fields ?action=&user=

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, clean-urls

Sorry if this question has been asked a ton however, I couldn't find a solution based off previous questions asked on this site and google.

I have this URL `http://mywebsite.com/index.php?action=users&user=John` to generate a profile for a user. I would like to clean this URL so I can simply type `http://mywebsite.com/users/John` or any action. Now, to go to a specific action, I can simply use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteBase /


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ index.php?action=$1 [L]
```

then visit `http://mywebsite.com/users` to visit the users page but to access a specific user I have `&users=John`. I thought I could simply use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteBase /


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?action=$1&$2=$3
```

to make my URL work like so `http://mywebsite.com/action/extra_action`. Confusing? Without cleaning the url I would have `http://mywebsite.com/index.php?action=ACTION&OTHER=`. Some actions don't require `&other=` and would lead to a different page if you add on to it. For example, `/index.php?action=users` leads to a page where a list is generated; `index.php?action=users&user=John` leads to a dynamic profile of John. I would like to make the URL `http://mywebsite.com/users` or if they want to visit a profile `/users/John`. Thanks for reading!

Comment: What other "actions" do you have?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.htaccess for friendly URL with multiple variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451886/htaccess-for-friendly-url-with-multiple-variables)

Comment: users, gametypes   users can have `&user=` and gametypes can have `&type=` on it.

Comment: @LozCherone It's not quite the same question, as there are conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the `/` and the last two parameters optional, otherwise the redirects will not work unless they have two `/`.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)(/?)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?(/?)([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?$ index.php?action=$1&$3=$5
```

Comment: Can I have multiple RewriteRules for each situation?

Comment: @davidxd33 Sorry, I misunderstood you the first time. See edit.

Comment: No problem, this works well expect for when adding the extra parameter it doesn't go to the correct page. `site.com/users` works but `site.com/users/John` redirects to `/users`. It could be how I serve the pages causing this. On users.php, I check to see if `$_GET['user']` isset then I serve the dynamic profile. If it isn't set, I render the users page. Could that be the problem? Thanks for helping with with this. I understand the logic of that rule though. It looks like it should work.

Comment: One more problem I discovered, when accessing a directory, `site.com/directory` it redirects to `site.com/directory?action=directory`