# How to make clean urls with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have this profile page which will show your profile with the url

```
localhost:8080/profile?username=ImSchnebz
```

But the thing is I want it to look like this:

```
localhost:8080/profile/ImSchnebz
```

I have tried a lot of different answers, but most of them give me 404 not found or 500 internal server error, I know this isn't anything you guys could help me with, but I've asked this question before, and gotten no response, so please, if there is anyone out there, please help me! :)

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I have this code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And it works perfectly with `localhost:8080/ImSchnebz` but I want it to be `localhost:8080/profile/ImSchnebz`

Comment: Here, this might help you http://forum.codecall.net/topic/74170-clean-urls-with-php/ I will be honest modding an htaccess is not my strong point so I was happy when I saw this way to get it back into php.. I hope it helps

Comment: Here is a great article on this topic: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/

Comment: this example is really clean and easy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451886/htaccess-for-friendly-url-with-multiple-variables

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/profile/(.*)$ /profile?username=$1 [NC]
```

Based on the link @Lawrence gave.

Comment: Nope, just getting 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: @ImSchnebz,do you have any css in your files?

Comment: it should maybe be without the /profile RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ /profile?username=$1 [NC]

Comment: Grep the Apache error logs for details. I'd guess, `mod_rewrite` isn't activated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This kinda works, not it just gives me this message: `No such user: ImSchnebz.php/ImSchnebz`