# .htaccess $_GET-Redirection didn't work

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, webserver

I will redirect this url with help from mod_rewrite

```
http://www.example.org/site/asd
```

to

```
http://www.example.org/index.php?site=asd
```

On my webserver, mod_rewrite is enabled, but my example didn't works: (.htaccess)

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/site/$ index.php?site=$
```

it makes nothing, no fail but it didn't works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets break it down

`RewriteRule ^(.*)/site/$ index.php?site=$`

The rule is only going to match urls like:

```
http://example.com/yada/yada/site/
http://example.com/something/site/
```

Which is backwards to what you want, so use a rule like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^site/(.*)$ index.php?site=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Which will match rules like:

```
http://example.com/site/yada/yada/
http://example.com/site/something/site/
http://example.com/site/no/slash
http://example.com/site/with/params/?abc=efg
```

Comment: np, thanks for the accept, I +1'nd you back ͡° ͜ʖ ͡°, I though it was what you wanted, the original match before *site* dont make much sense. You might also be interested in doing it anouther way, where you pass *everything* to index.php and route the path with PHP, this way you wont need lots of rules for each route/page path. So like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12451886/htaccess-for-friendly-url-with-multiple-variables/12451943#12451943

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting as,

`RewriteRule    ^(.*)/site/([a-z]+)$    index.php?site=$1    [L]`

Comment: okay, i think it works, but there is a blank page. My Htaccess is one folder down. And he redirect me to the index on this folder, but he sol redirect me in to the folder which is the index.php right now.

Comment: This will only match `/yada/site/somthing`, its not what the OP asked for. and pass only `yada` to ?site

Comment: @LozCheroneツ: As per the OP's question, he want to send the value after `site/` as `site=value` to index.php. That's it.